# Glue for shredded cork

Tags: adhesive, cork

My inlay soles are wearing and renewing them is expensive (they are custom made for my feet). I decided to make my own by making a mold and filling the mold with shredded cork. I have not done any experiments jet but was planning on using wood adhesive to turn the granulated cork into one piece of agglomerated cork. What adhesive should I use for cork?

Clay mold:

[image: The mold for inlay sole]

Example of agglomerated cork from wikimedia:

[image]

Comment: Wine corks and other mass produced cork items are made in a mold with machine created compression, while you might be able to re-produce this compression at home for a FLAT cork surface I doubt seriously you will be able to achieve this for your inlay soles.

Comment: @Tyson are you speaking from experience or is it your intuition? I was thinking of maybe finishing the surface with a dremel, I got the idea from having seen people using CNC machines on cork which gave a satisfying smooth surface.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about shoe repair, not Home Improvement.

Comment: @NiallC. No I do not agree, it is on cork adhesives, I thought this would be the perfect place to ask because granulated cork is often used as flooring for homes. I could have made an "artificial" question asking about how to use the granulated cork for a cork floor, but it doesn't make a significant different question+answer.

Comment: No do-it-yourselfer manufactures his own cork flooring. Even if he did, that border on hobbies and not mainstream home improvement.

Comment: you could also try to answer it then I will remove my question, or you could suggest where to ask it.

Comment: I can't delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found [a website](http://www.wineanorak.com/corks/makingtechnicalcorks.htm) describing parts of the process, the wine bottle corks are produced here with polyurethane. It also seems to be frequently used in cork floors.

Answer (score 0):

Buy sheet cork and build the volume you want out of contours.  Plain rubber cement or shoe glue will suffice.  You have to cut them out everytime but only have to design it once.